# VNC only display a terminal window

Tags: vnc, jessie-lite

I install the operating system from matlab support package.
Actually,it is debian 8.
After install **tightvncserver**,I try to log in desktop.
Only get this:(no iron of raspberrypi)
[image]

What happened?
How to fix it?

PS:About this operating system
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What version of Raspbian Jessie you running (Lite or Full)?

Lite version does not come with a x server.

To sum up you'd need to get GUI system, that would be:

- `apt-get install lxde`
- `apt-get install lightdm`

These should drag in `X` and other dependencies if they are not there already. If you wish to start `X` from the command line using startx or xinit, you'll need:

- `apt-get install xinit`

Use

- `sudo raspi-config` to boot to desktop.